Error in ros_cross_compile
I would like to create a cross-compilation environment for ROS2 applications.
I ran ros_cross_compile based on the tutorial section here and got the following error.
$ ros_cross_compile . --rosdistro foxy --arch aarch64 --os ubuntu --colcon-defaults ./defaults.yaml
INFO:Rosdep Gatherer:Building rosdep collector image: ros_cross_compile:rosdep
INFO:Docker Client:Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:focal
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 9df6d6105df2
INFO:Docker Client:Step 2/10 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y       gnupg     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 6594101c23af
INFO:Docker Client:Step 3/10 : RUN apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> a761f945f718
INFO:Docker Client:Step 4/10 : RUN echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 4bc0374ea03d
INFO:Docker Client:Step 5/10 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y       python3-rosdep       python3-colcon-common-extensions     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 692960d7ca4e
INFO:Docker Client:Step 6/10 : RUN rosdep init
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 5603a553e92e
INFO:Docker Client:Step 7/10 : COPY gather_rosdeps.sh /root/
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 67b66ab88c46
INFO:Docker Client:Step 8/10 : RUN mkdir -p /ws
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 8547d11eee68
INFO:Docker Client:Step 9/10 : WORKDIR /ws
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> aa0c783f3e1d
INFO:Docker Client:Step 10/10 : ENTRYPOINT ["/root/gather_rosdeps.sh"]
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> ec0f3b3f7d53
INFO:Docker Client:Successfully built ec0f3b3f7d53
INFO:Docker Client:Successfully tagged ros_cross_compile:rosdep
INFO:Rosdep Gatherer:Running rosdep collector image on workspace /home/nakajima/cross_compile_ws
INFO:Docker Client:+ '[' '!' -d ./src ']'
INFO:Docker Client:+ '[' -f /usercustom/rosdep_setup ']'
INFO:Docker Client:++ dirname cc_internals/aarch64-ubuntu-foxy/install_rosdeps.sh
INFO:Docker Client:+ out_dir=cc_internals/aarch64-ubuntu-foxy
INFO:Docker Client:+ mkdir -p cc_internals/aarch64-ubuntu-foxy
INFO:Docker Client:+ rosdep update --include-eol-distros
INFO:Docker Client:reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
INFO:Docker Client:Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
INFO:Docker Client:Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
INFO:Docker Client:Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
INFO:Docker Client:Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
INFO:Docker Client:Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
INFO:Docker Client:Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index-v4.yaml
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "ardent"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "bouncy"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "crystal"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "dashing"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "eloquent"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "foxy"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "galactic"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "groovy"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "humble"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "hydro"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "indigo"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "iron"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "jade"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "jazzy"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "kinetic"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "lunar"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "melodic"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "noetic"
INFO:Docker Client:Add distro "rolling"
INFO:Docker Client:updated cache in /root/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
INFO:Docker Client:Warning: running 'rosdep update' as root is not recommended.
INFO:Docker Client:  You should run 'sudo rosdep fix-permissions' and invoke 'rosdep update' again without sudo.
INFO:Docker Client:+ cat
INFO:Docker Client:+ mapfile -t package_paths
INFO:Docker Client:++ colcon list -p
INFO:Docker Client:+ rosdep install --os ubuntu:focal --rosdistro foxy --from-paths src/demos/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_cpp src/demos/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_interfaces src/demos/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_py src/demos/composition src/demos/demo_nodes_cpp src/demos/demo_nodes_cpp_native src/demos/demo_nodes_py src/demos/dummy_robot/dummy_map_server src/demos/dummy_robot/dummy_robot_bringup src/demos/dummy_robot/dummy_sensors src/demos/image_tools src/demos/intra_process_demo src/demos/lifecycle src/demos/logging_demo src/demos/pendulum_control src/demos/pendulum_msgs src/demos/quality_of_service_demo/rclcpp src/demos/quality_of_service_demo/rclpy src/demos/topic_monitor --ignore-src --reinstall --default-yes --skip-keys '' --simulate
INFO:Docker Client:+ grep -v 'apt-get install -y' /tmp/all-deps.sh
INFO:Docker Client:+ grep 'apt-get install -y' /tmp/all-deps.sh
INFO:Docker Client:++ awk '{print $4}' 'ORS= '
INFO:Docker Client:+ echo 'apt-get install -y ros-foxy-lifecycle-msgs ros-foxy-rclcpp-lifecycle ros-foxy-std-msgs ros-foxy-ament-cmake ros-foxy-ament-lint-auto ros-foxy-ament-lint-common ros-foxy-ros-testing ros-foxy-rclcpp ros-foxy-rclcpp-action ros-foxy-rclcpp-components ros-foxy-example-interfaces ros-foxy-rcutils ros-foxy-rmw ros-foxy-rmw-implementation-cmake ros-foxy-launch-ros ros-foxy-launch-xml ros-foxy-ament-cmake-pytest ros-foxy-launch ros-foxy-launch-testing ros-foxy-launch-testing-ament-cmake ros-foxy-launch-testing-ros libopencv-dev ros-foxy-sensor-msgs ros-foxy-ament-cmake-gtest ros-foxy-builtin-interfaces ros-foxy-rosidl-default-generators ros-foxy-rosidl-default-runtime ros-foxy-nav-msgs ros-foxy-rmw-fastrtps-cpp ros-foxy-action-msgs ros-foxy-rclpy ros-foxy-ament-copyright ros-foxy-ament-flake8 ros-foxy-ament-pep257 python3-pytest ros-foxy-rttest ros-foxy-tlsf-cpp ros-foxy-ros2run ros-foxy-rosidl-cmake ros-foxy-ament-index-python ros-foxy-robot-state-publisher '
INFO:Docker Client:+ chmod +x cc_internals/aarch64-ubuntu-foxy/install_rosdeps.sh
INFO:Docker Client:+ chown -R 1000 cc_internals/aarch64-ubuntu-foxy
INFO:ros_cross_compile.sysroot_creator:Building sysroot image: nakajima/aarch64-ubuntu-foxy:latest
INFO:Docker Client:Step 1/31 : ARG BASE_IMAGE
INFO:Docker Client:Step 2/31 : FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 2788af2ba581
INFO:Docker Client:Step 3/31 : ARG ROS_VERSION
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 5954b06c7f3f
INFO:Docker Client:Step 4/31 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 4e9971ca27c7
INFO:Docker Client:Step 5/31 : COPY bin/* /usr/bin/
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> fa3475a4317e
INFO:Docker Client:Step 6/31 : RUN echo 'Etc/UTC' > /etc/timezone &&     ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> bcfc60b765f8
INFO:Docker Client:Step 7/31 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y         tzdata         locales     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 39dfb246c371
INFO:Docker Client:Step 8/31 : RUN echo 'en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8' >> /etc/locale.gen &&     locale-gen &&     update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 418cb2ed5fc5
INFO:Docker Client:Step 9/31 : ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 2e453ecb360b
INFO:Docker Client:Step 10/31 : ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 09fe08f179e4
INFO:Docker Client:Step 11/31 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y         ca-certificates         curl         gnupg         lsb-release     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> b9f5c3f1bf9b
INFO:Docker Client:Step 12/31 : RUN if [[ "${ROS_VERSION}" == "ros2" ]]; then       curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg;       echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/${ROS_VERSION}/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" |           tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null;     else       curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | apt-key add - ;       echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/${ROS_VERSION}/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main"           > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/${ROS_VERSION}-latest.list;     fi
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> f3715b5db6c5
INFO:Docker Client:Step 13/31 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y       build-essential       cmake       python3-colcon-common-extensions       python3-colcon-mixin       python3-dev       python3-pip     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 1115645c7779
INFO:Docker Client:Step 14/31 : RUN python3 -m pip install -U     setuptools
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Using cache
INFO:Docker Client: ---> 8ad9f2030fae
INFO:Docker Client:Step 15/31 : RUN if [[ "${ROS_VERSION}" == "ros2" ]]; then     python3 -m pip install -U     flake8     flake8-blind-except     flake8-builtins     flake8-class-newline     flake8-comprehensions     flake8-deprecated     flake8-docstrings     flake8-import-order     flake8-quotes     pytest-repeat     pytest-rerunfailures     pytest     pytest-cov     pytest-runner   ; fi
INFO:Docker Client: ---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64/v2) and no specific platform was requested
INFO:Docker Client: ---> Running in e0267fa8e093
INFO:Docker Client:Collecting flake8
INFO:Docker Client:  Downloading flake8-7.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
INFO:Docker Client:Collecting flake8-blind-except
INFO:Docker Client:  Downloading flake8-blind-except-0.2.1.tar.gz (3.7 kB)
INFO:Docker Client:    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-11jjamn2/flake8-blind-except/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-11jjamn2/flake8-blind-except/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-11jjamn2/flake8-blind-except/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-11jjamn2/flake8-blind-except/
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
        from .dist import Distribution
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 18, in <module>
        from . import (
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_entry_points.py", line 45, in <module>
        def validate(eps: metadata.EntryPoints):
    AttributeError: module 'importlib_metadata' has no attribute 'EntryPoints'
    ----------------------------------------

INFO:Docker Client:ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

ERROR:Docker Client:Error building Docker image. The follow error was caught:
The command '/bin/bash -c if [[ "${ROS_VERSION}" == "ros2" ]]; then     python3 -m pip install -U     flake8     flake8-blind-except     flake8-builtins     flake8-class-newline     flake8-comprehensions     flake8-deprecated     flake8-docstrings     flake8-import-order     flake8-quotes     pytest-repeat     pytest-rerunfailures     pytest     pytest-cov     pytest-runner   ; fi' returned a non-zero code: 1
NoneType: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nakajima/.local/bin/ros_cross_compile", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/nakajima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros_cross_compile/ros_cross_compile.py", line 237, in main
    cross_compile_pipeline(args, data_collector, platform)
  File "/home/nakajima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros_cross_compile/ros_cross_compile.py", line 224, in cross_compile_pipeline
    stage(platform, docker_client, ros_workspace_dir, options, data_collector)
  File "/home/nakajima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros_cross_compile/sysroot_creator.py", line 172, in __call__
    create_workspace_sysroot_image(docker_client, platform)
  File "/home/nakajima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros_cross_compile/sysroot_creator.py", line 143, in create_workspace_sysroot_image
    docker_client.build_image(
  File "/home/nakajima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros_cross_compile/docker_client.py", line 74, in build_image
    self._process_build_log(log_generator)
  File "/home/nakajima/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros_cross_compile/docker_client.py", line 84, in _process_build_log
    raise docker.errors.BuildError(error_line)
docker.errors.BuildError: The command '/bin/bash -c if [[ "${ROS_VERSION}" == "ros2" ]]; then     python3 -m pip install -U     flake8     flake8-blind-except     flake8-builtins     flake8-class-newline     flake8-comprehensions     flake8-deprecated     flake8-docstrings     flake8-import-order     flake8-quotes     pytest-repeat     pytest-rerunfailures     pytest     pytest-cov     pytest-runner   ; fi' returned a non-zero code: 1

environment:
Windows10 + VirtualBox 7.0.12 + Ubuntu 20.04
How can I resolve this?
